# Importing <filesystem> in gcc

Tags: c++, stl, g++, c++-modules

Importing filesystem has caused issues with my project as it seems to be clashing with memory.

```
g++ -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -xc++-system-header memory
g++ -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -xc++-system-header filesystem
g++ -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -xc++-system-header iostream
```

```
import <memory>;
import <filesystem>;
import <iostream>;      

int main()
{
    std::cout << "winner" <<  std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the following error

```
➜ g++ -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -o main main.cpp
main.cpp: In destructor ‘constexpr std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_M_construct(_InIterator, _InIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag)::_Guard::~_Guard() [with _InIterator = const wchar_t*; _CharT = wchar_t; _Traits = std::char_traits<wchar_t>; _Alloc = std::allocator<wchar_t>]’:
main.cpp:10:14: warning: ignoring attributes applied to ‘std::auto_ptr< <template-parameter-1-1> >’ after definition [-Wattributes]
   10 |         std::cout << "winner" <<  std::endl;
      |              ^~~~
main.cpp:10:14: note: during load of pendings for ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string’
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:10:14: note: during load of binding ‘std::cout’
```

Moving filesystem forward solves the error

```
import <filesystem>;
import <memory>;
import <iostream>;      

int main()
{
    std::cout << "winner" <<  std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But trying to use it does the same thing

```
import <filesystem>;
import <memory>;
import <iostream>;      

std::filesystem::path global;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "winner" <<  std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
➜  g++ -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -o main main.cpp
main.cpp: In destructor ‘constexpr std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_M_construct(_InIterator, _InIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag)::_Guard::~_Guard() [with _InIterator = const char*; _CharT = char8_t; _Traits = std::char_traits<char8_t>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char8_t>]’:
main.cpp:6:18: warning: ignoring attributes applied to ‘std::auto_ptr< <template-parameter-1-1> >’ after definition [-Wattributes]
    6 | std::filesystem::path global;
      |                  ^~~~
main.cpp:6:18: note: during load of pendings for ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string’
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:6:18: note: during load of binding ‘std::filesystem::__cxx11::path’
```

Will I just have to wait for P2465R3?